# Collecting grep output via os.system() in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use this Ubuntu command on a Linux OS in python

```
cmd = "grep -n 'str' file.txt"
```

in the script, im trying to use

```
command = os.system(cmd)
```

but when i try to print the variable, it only prints a `'0'`, but in the output appears `1:str`. Is there a way to make set this output as a variable?

Comment: Not specific to repl.it; this behavior is identical everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `0` because that's the exit code of the process.  Per the documentation for `os.system()`:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process

To get the behavior you want, use the `subprocess` package instead, like this:

```
import subprocess
command = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```